# Granting daemon permissions to read/write to a folder owned by user

Tags: server, permissions, 17.04, transmission

I recently installed Transmission and I'm trying to give it the ability to download files directly onto a ZFS storage pool that is owned by my main users. However, for now it says that permissions are denied. I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve this issue.

I've tried to change the user that the daemon runs as but I can't seem to get that to work and it seems like a pretty deep rabbit hole of bugs anyway.

So what I'd like is to just grant `transmission-daemon` permission to read/write anything in `/Storage/Downloads/Torrents`.

If possible I want to avoid granting everyone permission or granting permission just to `transmission-daemon` as other things need access, too.

Comment: Perhaps a group access would help, then add any user who needs access to that group.

Comment: Totally solved my issue! TL:DR; I kept myself as the user on the account but changed that folder's group to Transmissions (then just added myself to the group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to create a group, then make that group the owners of that folder and add any who needs access to that group. And of course control group access using that group.

Steps:

1. Create new group (with any name):

   ```
   sudo addgroup <any_name>
   ```
2. Make group owner of said folder:

   ```
   sudo chgrp -R <any_name> /Storage/Downloads/Torrents
   ```
3. Change the permissions on the said folder:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 770 /Storage/Downloads/Torrents
   ```

Now simply add any one you like to that group to grant them access.

Comment: Permissions should be always be tight as possible. So the "other" should not be set to "5" (world read & execute). Maybe  770 is good enough.

Comment: @lkj your right updated that.